# Break program execution on errors approach

Tags: c, error-handling

I am using the following approach to break on errors (similar to VS Break debugger when exceptions are thrown in C#):

```
        ...
        NTSTATUS status = ZwClose(handle);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            DbgBreakPoint();
            return status;
        }
```

If NTSTATUS is not success, I am setting a breakpoint in the program.  It is convenient because I 
need not have to manually set up tons of breakpoints in code. I want to see the error when it fails first.
First question how do you like this approach to be used in code? I don't saw anything like that.

Second question how do define macros like NT_SUCCESS_FOO to use instead of [NT_SUCCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565436(v=vs.85).aspx) that will add DbgBreakPoint() automatically
in the case of  NT_SUCCESS returns true? I am not very experienced in macroses ..

Comment: Don't you want a breakpoint when `NT_SUCCESS` returns `false`?

Comment: @meaning-matters if NT_SUCCESS - returns false, that mean that functions returns error, so I want to make a breakpoint. if true - I don;t need a breakpoint, that is success.